# stripos doesn't work if I give negative offset

Tags: php

In the following code If I search for a character position without giving the offset it works(uses the default positive index, starts from 0),prints 0

```
$str = "abcdashboard";
$s = 'a';
$pos = stripos($str,$s);
if($pos !==FALSE){
    echo 'positive: character found'.$pos;
}
```

But if I use negative index, want to start the search from last it's not working.. prints nothing

```
$str = "abcdashboard";
$s = 'a';
$neg = stripos($str,$s,-1);
if($neg !==FALSE){

    echo 'negative: character found'.$neg;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

I don't get it from the following

**offset**
If specified, search will start this number of characters counted from the beginning of the string. If the offset is negative, the search will start this number of characters counted from the end of the string.

Comment: [`stripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) **does not** search from the end of the string towards its beginning. Its third argument tells it where to start searching. `-1` means check only the last character of the haystack string (the first argument). If you want to search from the end towards the beginning, try [`strripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strripos.php) (the second `r` in its name comes from *"reverse"*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`stripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) **does not** search from the end of the string towards its beginning. Its third argument tells it where to start searching, but it still searches from that index towards the end of the string.

`-1` tells it to check only the last character of the haystack string (the first argument).

If you want to search from the end towards the beginning, try [`strripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strripos.php).

---

The second `r` in the name of string functions [`strrchr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php), [`strrpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) and [`strripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strripos.php) comes from *"reverse"*. These functions search their second argument (`string $needle`) into their first argument (`string $haystack`) starting from the specified position (by default the end of the string) towards the beginning of the `$haystack` string.

Consequently they find the *last* occurrence of `$needle` into `$haystack` as opposed to the similar functions without the second `r` in their names that find the *first* occurrence.

The semantic of the third argument (`int $offset`) is the same as for the other string searching functions: positive values (and `0`) start counting from the beginning of `$haystack`, negative values sets the start position by counting from the end of `$haystack`.

Answer (score 4):

That should work.

```
stripos($str,$s,-4);
```

will search in last 4 chars and output

```
negative: character found 9
```